# API Gateway latency vs integration latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

For AWS' API Gateway, my understanding is that *Integration Latency should always be less than Latency* (see [Amazon API Gateway dimensions and metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html)).

However, when I compare the two, I am always getting the *opposite order*. This is true whether I look at the API Gateway Dashboard or view the metrics in Amazon CloudWatch. Some examples (I have little enough traffic to be able to compare individual data points)

```java
 1. 2024-01-23 18:15 UTC: Integration Latency = 1235ms vs Latency = 628ms
 2. 2024-01-23 14:20 UTC: Integration Latency = 1582ms vs Latency = 802ms
 3. 2024-01-23  8:35 UTC: Integration Latency = 1207ms vs Latency = 614ms
```

Since the gap is large and consistently in the 'wrong' order, I have to assume my understanding of API Gateway metrics is incorrect. But how?

- Are the two latency metrics disjoint (so user will be waiting the sum of Latency + Integration Latency time)?
- Or is my understanding reversed (so Integration Latency >= Latency, where Integration Latency = Latency + API Gateway overhead).

In all 3 of the above examples my Lambda function took ~450ms (+/- 35ms). Via lambda function's Monitor > Duration graph, as well as its CloudWatch logs.